# How to write a startup script

Tags: scripts

I want to write a startup script file, that start my kafka environment.

I tried as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/zkServer.sh start
/usr/local/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /usr/local/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/config/server.properties
```

The problem is, it starts only the zookeeper but not kafka server.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this script doesn't need sudo privileges.

One way to autostart a script is use a Desktop Autostarting method.

**In Ubuntu you can do it like this,**

- Create a file in .config/autostart from your home directory with an extension of .desktop

Say you created zookeeper.desktop then open and include this format.

**For Zookeeper Entry**

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=Zookeeper

Exec=/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.11/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

Then create a separate one for:

**For Kafra Entry**

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=kafra

Exec=/usr/local/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon /usr/local/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/config/server.properties
```

or just the script your made

**For your Script Entry**

```
[Desktop Entry]

Type=Application

Name=/name/of/your/script

Exec=/path/to/your/script
```

Then you can do it like this(sudo)

add the path of your script to /etc/rc.local(open and edit rc.local)

/path/to/your/script &

exit 0

if it doesn't exist but it your system have /etc/rc.d1 to 6
just simply add your script inside that folder and will be executed with sudo rights.

Comment: I've forgot to mentioned. The script needs sudo privileges.

Comment: Edited, just now

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the approach described above is to modify the Exec command in the .desktop file as follows:

```
    Exec=gnome-terminal -- /path/to/your/script.sh start
```

This has two advantages

1. You can store your script anywhere you like without having to modify anything in rc.local or /etc
2. You launch the script within a new terminal window which allows you to see the prompt of the script and e.g. type in a required sudo password in case your script contains a sudo command.